# Stuck on 'Establishing secure connection' in Chrome for one website

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to access https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/account/re-register.html in Chrome and it is getting stuck on 'establishing secure connection'.

Other secure sites work fine and the above works fine in Firefox or IE.

I have cleared cache etc.

If I run Fiddler I can access the site (as it goes through Fiddler's certs) so clearly an issue with this one certificate.

Comment: Could be this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303398

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it begins to issue "establishing secure connection" if I install Data Saver extension. Solved the problem by uninstalling it.

Comment: My problem solved by disabling ublock origin. Thanks, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Have you at some stage installed [Comodo Dragon](https://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php)? It has been known to cause problems with SSL.

[This link](http://www.jonas-lieb.de/blog/2013/12/13/fixing-chrome-ssl-connection-error-caused-by-comodo-products/) will take you to a page which deals with fixing the issue if this is the case